# Discord.py Timeout server members

Tags: python, discord.py, timeout

A few months ago I came up with the idea to make a functional discord bot for my friend's server. My friend asked me if I could make a member timeout command, so I started my research. Since discord.py will not be updated anymore, this question might be useless and time wasting, but I really want to try it anyways. I know Stack Overflow is about modifying code and not a code-writing service, but I genuinely don't know how I should do this.

My ideas were giving a member a 'Muted' or 'Timed Out' role for the specified time and removing it again after the timer stops, but then I am supposed to use a while loop causing the rest of the code to not be accessible anymore, same goes for using the `time.sleep` function.

I couldn't find anything about this on the internet, so my only hope is Stack Overflow. I don't want you to write entire programs in your answer, just where I might be looking for, so that I can figer the rest out myself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Discord recently released a timeout feature which is really good and takes away your problems of creating/removing a role with no send message perms. Discord.py may not recieve updates but, that does not stop you to write your own requests to discord API, or you can also use one of the forks which have already implemented this.

Here is one simple non-bot script I wrote to make it work:

```py
import pprint
import requests
import datetime

BASE = "https://discord.com/api/v9/"
TOKEN = "BOT TOKEN" 


def timeout_user(*, user_id: int, guild_id: int, until: int):
    endpoint = f'guilds/{guild_id}/members/{user_id}'
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bot {TOKEN}"}
    url = BASE + endpoint
    timeout = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=time_in_mins)).isoformat()
    json = {'communication_disabled_until': timeout}
    session = requests.patch(url, json=json, headers=headers)
    if session.status_code in range(200, 299):
        return session.json()
    else: 
        return print("Did not find any\n", session.status_code)

guild_id = 231
user_id = 123
time_in_mins = 2
member = timeout_user(user_id=user_id, guild_id=guild_id,until=time_in_mins)
pprint.pprint(member)
```

```json
{'avatar': None,
 'communication_disabled_until': '2021-12-23T09:49:58.965896+00:00',
 'deaf': False,
 'is_pending': False,
 'joined_at': '2021-12-23T09:06:30.927000+00:00',
 'mute': False,
 'nick': None,
 'pending': False,
 'premium_since': None,
 'roles': [],
 'user': {'avatar': 'avatar hash string',
          'discriminator': '1234',
          'id': 'Member ID',
          'public_flags': 128,
          'username': 'Member Name'}}
```

Since `discord.py` is asynchronous, you might want an asynchronous code.
Here is one quick integration

```py
import aiohttp
import discord
import datetime
import warnings
from discord.ext import commands

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=['$',], intents=intents)
bot.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user.name} is ready to go!")

async def timeout_user(*, user_id: int, guild_id: int, until):
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bot {bot.http.token}"}
    url = f"https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/{guild_id}/members/{user_id}"
    timeout = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=until)).isoformat()
    json = {'communication_disabled_until': timeout}
    async with bot.session.patch(url, json=json, headers=headers) as session:
        if session.status in range(200, 299):
           return True
        return False


@bot.command()
async def timeout(ctx: commands.Context, member: discord.Member, until: int):
    handshake = await timeout_user(user_id=member.id, guild_id=ctx.guild.id, until=until)
    if handshake:
         return await ctx.send(f"Successfully timed out user for {until} minutes.")
    await ctx.send("Something went wrong")

bot.run("BOT TOKEN")
```

You can read more about the endpoint [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#modify-guild-member)

Comment: Okay it seems like it's working! One final question, should I save the JSON code to a different file or can I just include it in my python code?

Comment: @Itsjul1an which json code you might be referring to?

Comment: oh wait, the json I attached? You don't have to save that json code. It was just a response that the API sends you back on successful member timeout edit. No need to worry about that.

Comment: Hopefully one of you get this and answer, I want to add this to my moderation bot is there a way to untime them out after you use this method? Or no

Comment: @SpacedOutKID, I wrote this when `discord.py` was discontinued. It is now back in development and implements this feature as [`member.timeout()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.timeout), and I will recommend you to use that instead of this code!

Comment: Its back in development?? Dope did not know I appreciate that youre actually clutch ima check it out